# Cname issue on Wix

Tags: cname-record

So I built my wix website and was going to connect it to my domain via pointing. I have followed all the steps given by wix.

1. To add the CNAME and Value
2. To add the A and value
   [Screenshot of Wix Instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw0o7.jpg)

But no matter how many times I do it, it just won't connect. 
[Screenshot of DNS Records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf2fB.png)

I have contacted Wix but they aren't very helpful and said that I keyed in my CNAME wrongly. It seems that my domain name keeps popping up at the end of my cname.

[whatsmydns screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rTIC.png)

Could someone be so kind as to advice me what am I doing wrong? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You and Wix have both forgotten the required `.` at the end of the CNAME value.

Without the dot at the end, your domain is appended to the record.

`www`, therefore, should be a `CNAME` to `www3.wixdns.net.` with the full stop at the end.

But, when I queried your live DNS records, the dot already seems to be present.

```
www.greensynergy.my is an alias for www3.wixdns.net.
```

So perhaps you already fixed it, after taking the screenshot?

Comment: Thank you so much for that! =D yes, somehow realized that the dot was missing. Hahaha. But thank you so much. =)